# next view controller is not loaded when the segue is performed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I am still new to the storyboard stuff. I spent two days debugging this problem. It seems the destination view controller of a segue is not working properly when the `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` is called.

I have a table view and when a cell is tapped, it calls for a segue

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    VAItem *item = [category itemAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueShowDetail" sender:item];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueShowDetail"]) {

        VADetailViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailViewController.item = (VAItem*) sender; // <-- THIS ASSIGNMENT DOES NOT WORK       
    }
}
```

My debugging shows, the `item` is correctly passed down to `prepareForSegue` but the `detailViewController.item` is a wild pointer. It's not initialized and the `=` assignment does not have any effect.

I put a breakpoint in VADetailViewController's `viewDidLoad` and found out that the `item` variable is still the wild pointer address even though the assignment has taken place.

```
@interface VADetailViewController : UIViewController
// data
@property (nonatomic, retain) VAItem *item;
@end
```

item is also correctly synthesized.

Any help is much appreciated

Leo

Comment: there seems to be a bug in xcode that the debugger shows the assignment did not take effect but actually it did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a storyboard segue to transition to the next viewcontroller you don't need to use `tableVeiew:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in this situation.  Depending how you have things set up that could be contributing to the problem.

In your storyboard, make sure you have drawn your push segue from your tableview's Prototype Cell to the detail view controller (i.e. from the cell, **NOT** from the tableViewController).  If you have your storyboard set up that way your segue will be triggered as soon as the user selects a cell.  A reference to the cell itself will be passed to `prepareForSegue:sender:` as the `sender` parameter.  You can then inspect that object to find out which row was clicked in that method.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueShowDetail"]) {

        // sender will be the tableview cell that was selected
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        VAItem *item = [category itemAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        VADetailViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailViewController.item = item;       
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath because tapping one of my cell is calling the a telephone number. I don't know how can I create a segue in the storyboard if I don't have a destination view controller in my application for this.

Answer (score 0):

You really only want to use one of

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

to pass your data along to the next view controller. If you want to use the latter in your case, then you need to change your code to something along the lines of:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueShowDetail"]) {

    VADetailViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    detailViewController.item = [catagory itemAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
}
```

I think you were getting an error because of what you assigned your sender. Here is the reference to the docs that explain what 'sender' should be.

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:

Hope this helps.